# How to modify CMakeLists.txt to customize test target

Tags: cmake, gnu-make, ctest

I have complicated project - a big tree, with CMakeLists.txt in each directory.

Once the cmake is done, the `Makefile` has `test` target which states

```
.PHONY test
test:
   $(SHELL) -c
   "$(CTEST) $(CTEST_FLAGS) --test-dir $(BUILD_PATH)"
```

The problem is that the tests requires some pre-setup (temp directories to be create, environment variables to set, etc).

So if I were working with a clean `make`, I would just modify the `Makefile` to this:

```
.PHONY test
test:
   $(SHELL) -c
   "source $(BUILD_PATH)/setup_tests.sh && \
    $(CTEST) $(CTEST_FLAGS) --test-dir $(BUILD_PATH)"
```

But the `Makefile` is created by `cmake` and I have no idea where to define such changes.

The root `CMakeLists.txt` has a function call `enable_tests()`. The `src/tests` directory has its own `CMakeLists.txt` but it just defines a bunch of subdirectories with individual tests.

Could someone point me in the direction on how to customize the execution of specific target in the `cmake`? Or does the `ctest` has option to run a shell script before all the tests (The `-S` looks promising but it requires cmake's language script? It does not work with the `.sh`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a custom command in Cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390236/running-a-custom-command-in-cmake)

Comment: @273K This is a problem different to the one linked. Even if `test` was a target created as described in the question, this question would require a modification of an existing custom target, but the linked question basically asks for the `add_custom_command` command. This question is about a special target created by cmake though, based on the `add_test` commands...

Answer (score 1):

The typical CMake way would be to use test properties:

```
set_tests_properties(mytest PROPERTIES
    ENVIRONMENT "VAR1=val1;VAR2=val2;VAR3=val3"
)
```

As with running a script to set the environment as opposed to the typical CMake way, you could simply set the command to run that script before the executable:

```
find_program(BASH_PROGRAM bash)
add_test(NAME mytest COMMAND
    ${BASH_PROGRAM} -c "source \"${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/setup_tests.sh\" && $<TARGET_FILE:myexec>"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The intended way to create this kind of logic would be to define a [fixture test for the setup](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/FIXTURES_REQUIRED.html):

For convenience we're simply running the following cmake script allowing us to specify a message in addition to allowing us to specify, if the test should fail, but you could run your own bash script as test instead.

**testscript.cmake**

```
#[===[
Params:
    MESSAGE: message to print
    FAIL   : fail the test?
]===]

if(FAIL)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "${MESSAGE}")
else()
    message(STATUS "${MESSAGE}")
endif()
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
enable_testing()

# the values of the FAIL parameter could be modified to to test different scenarios...
add_test(NAME Fixture COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D FAIL:BOOL=0 -D "MESSAGE:STRING=executing fixture" -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testscript.cmake)
add_test(NAME Test COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D FAIL:BOOL=0 -D "MESSAGE:STRING=executing actual test" -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testscript.cmake)
add_test(NAME Test2 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D FAIL:BOOL=1 -D "MESSAGE:STRING=executing test without fixture" -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testscript.cmake)

set_tests_properties(Fixture PROPERTIES FIXTURES_SETUP Setup)
set_tests_properties(Test PROPERTIES FIXTURES_REQUIRED Setup)
```

Now

```
ctest -R 'Test$' --verbose
```

Executes the `Fixture` test and if this test succeeds, the actual test requested (`Test`) is executed.

```
ctest -R Test2 --verbose
```

Just executes `Test2`.

You can add cleanup logic for tests in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

> some pre-setup (temp directories to be create, environment variables to set, etc).

Environment variables are set with `set_tests_properties` as in the other answer.

You can create a directory with `FILE(MAKE_DIRECTORY` from CMake

For an advanced journey, you may want to discover [test fixtures](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/FIXTURES_SETUP.html), which are meant to "prepare" the environment (*not* environment variables) for tests, for example run a service that tests need.

> how to customize the execution of specific target in the cmake?

`add_test` takes a command, you can run any command you want.

> does the ctest has option to run a shell script before all the tests

Why *all* the tests? Just the tests that need to run that shell - fixtures sound like they are for that.